# Python Turtle Wait for Keypress

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, fractals

I want to be to follow a turtle drawing step by step by making the user press a key before each movement.

I can do it with by asking for user input like so:

```
def wait():
    input('Press a key')
```

but this is a terrible solution as focus leaves the turtle window.

I am aware of `screen.listen()` and could set an event listener with `screen.onkeypress()`. - E.g `my_screen.onkeypress('wait')` but not sure how to implement this.

EDIT: I realise I should probably be more specific. I'm trying to trace thr recursion for the Koch curve. My code so far is below:

```
import turtle

def koch(t, order, size):
    """
       Make turtle t draw a Koch fractal of 'order' and 'size'.
       Leave the turtle facing the same direction.
    """
    wait_for_keypress()
    if order == 0:          # The base case is just a straight line
        t.forward(size)
    else:
        koch(t, order-1, size/3)   # Go 1/3 of the way
        t.left(60)
        koch(t, order-1, size/3)
        t.right(120)
        koch(t, order-1, size/3)
        t.left(60)
        koch(t, order-1, size/3)


def wait_for_keypress():
    input('Press a key') # There must be a better way

t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()
s.listen()

koch(t, 3, 100)

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a recursive generator!  We start the fractal code running but we use `yield` and `yield from` to make it stop each step along the way.  We then have the screen click event do a `next()` on our generator:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def koch(t, order, size):
    """
    Make turtle t draw a Koch fractal of 'order' and 'size'.
    Leave the turtle facing the same direction.
    """

    if order == 0:
        t.forward(size)  # The base case is just a straight line
        yield
    else:
        yield from koch(t, order - 1, size / 3)  # Go 1/3 of the way
        t.left(60)
        yield from koch(t, order - 1, size / 3)
        t.right(120)
        yield from koch(t, order - 1, size / 3)
        t.left(60)
        yield from koch(t, order - 1, size / 3)

def click_handler(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)  # disable handler while in handler

    try:
        next(generator)
    except StopIteration:
        return

    screen.onclick(click_handler)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()

generator = koch(turtle, 3, 200)

screen.onclick(click_handler)

screen.mainloop()
```

Run the program.  Each time you click the mouse on the window, you'll get an additional segment of your Koch fractal.  We can also make this work with a key event, keeping the imports and `koch()` routine the same:

```
...

def key_handler():
    screen.onkey(None, "Up")  # disable handler while in handler

    try:
        next(generator)
    except StopIteration:
        return

    screen.onkey(key_handler, "Up")

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()

generator = koch(turtle, 3, 200)

screen.onkey(key_handler, "Up")

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Note that this responds to up arrow keys presses in the turtle graphics window, not key presses in the console.

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to draw the fractal on a continuous basis by holding the "Up" key or mouse button down?

Answer (score 0):

change your function like this:

```
def wait_for_keypress():
    print("'Press a key'")
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    try:
        tty.setraw(fd)
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    except:
        pass
```

Based on [Manually control a Python Turtle with the keyboard.](https://gist.github.com/insom/6824537)

## Note:

you must import `sys`,`termios` and `tty`